# HTML -CSS- Where is my password and login information

Tags: html, css

So I am just practicing with some HTML-CSS login forms and I was trying to figure what to change to set my password to..

here is my code for the page:

```
<style>
      /* Full-width input fields */
    input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
     }

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
position: center;
bottom: 300;
right: 200;
 background: #046B8C;
padding: 14px 20px;
margin: 8px 0
color: blue;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100%;   
}   

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
width: auto;
padding: 10px 18px;
background-color: red;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
text-align: center;
margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
position: relative;
} 

img.avatar {
width: 40%;
border-radius: 50%;
}  

.container {
padding: 16px;
} 

span.psw {
float: right;
padding-top: 16px;
} 

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background: url(faq.png) ;

padding-top: 60px;
}

 /* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
background-color: black;
margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and           
           centered */
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
top: 0;
color: red;
font-size: 35px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: red;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
-webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
from {transform: scale(0)}
to {transform: scale(1)}
}

 /* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
 @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
span.psw {
   display: block;
   float: none;
}
.cancelbtn {
   width: 100%;
}
}
</style>
<body>



<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" action="confirmedlogin.php".>
<div class="imgcontainer">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
         class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>  
  <img src="login.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <label><b>Username</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

  <label><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw"     

 required>

  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
  </div>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
  <button type="button"         

onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
  <span class="psw">Forgot <a   

href="http://the4threich.pe.hu/login.php">password</a></span>
</div>
 </form>
</div>

<script>
 // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }
   } 
 </script>
```

Comment: Code is located at the4threich.pe.hu/login.php

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you use jsfiddle and strip out all code not relevant to the question, you'll get better answers.

Comment: That's site about Hitler, please don't help him :)

Comment: its about a group on a 6 year old server called 2b2t

Comment: David, What code have i stripped? if its not there goto http://www.the4threich.pe.hu/login.php